# What's the best way to earn OverCharge?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

I've worked my way through the main story and most side missions in *Sunset Overdrive*, and found that maybe I spent too much OverCharge on guns. I'd like to now buy some of the collectible maps, but I'm low on OverCharge, and haven't found a great/quick way to gain it. What is the best/quickest way to gain OverCharge? Is there a repeatable mission that is easiest to do over and over, or some task to gain it fast(er)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to earn overcharge after clearing all the quests is to play chaos squad mode. You must play it to completion and try to complete as many bonus objectives as you can. A good tip is to only use a fully upgraded hairspray launcher, all the single shot weapon damage badges, OD killer, OD rival, and the second amendment amp.

Once you complete a full set of chaos squad games and the final night defense, you will get to spin from 1 to 5 prize wheels, depending on your score. Unfortunately the rewards are random, so sometimes you can go quite a while without winning overcharge, and other times you can luck out and get three 5000 overcharge spins.

Alternate method:

You can replay the mission "Getting the band back together", and when you get to the part where all the drums are scattered about, just keep bouncing on one of them on killing OD (I recommend the weapon used above), rather than completing the mission. I've seen people get as much as 15k overcharge an hour doing this. Its much less fun and potentially slower than Chaos Squad, so I usually stick to the first method.

Comment: I don’t think Chaos Squad is available on the PC version of Sunset Overdrive.

Answer (score 0):

For all platforms, since you just want OverCharge for the collectible maps, you could save before buying them, check the map, take a screenshot, or memorize the locations, then reload the save to get your OverCharge back.

**Otherwise, if you don't want to save scum:**

In the base game, finding a mission that has a part that involves a specific target, while respawning other enemies, like in "This Ends Here", where after the skirmishes, the Tank Bot needs to be destroyed, but Rifle Bots seem to keep respawning endlessly, it seems.

Or summon OD with Taiko Drum bounces in "Getting The Band Back Together".

For weaponry, use only one weapon, since it seems like Ammo drops are set to only be for the weapon you're wielding.

For Amps, put "Mine all Mine" on your weapon, wear the Hero Amps of "Spread The Love" and "$Magnet$" for maximum durability and pick-up ability.

Don't pick an Epic Amp, unless you're really good at staying away from the Tank Bot if you're using "This Ends Here", or Bounce-Splosion if you're using the Taiko Drum.

Then for Overdrives, more damage, bigger magazines, and more durability are a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For a method requiring more player participation, Fast Travelling while in midair, for speed, to the Downtown Player Fort should respawn a Fizzco Truck visible in the minimap, which rewards ~100 OverCharge on average each opening.

The Taiko Drum method gives ~4 OverCharge a second, while, assuming a slow 10 seconds each Truck Opening, gives 10 OverCharge a second, a 2.5 increase in efficiency.

Respawning just one truck seems like they planned for that since I'm not seeing many / any 150+ OC drops from that truck if I loop it.

But, ping-ponging between the Brewery and Downtown Forts, since the Brewery seems to have a high chance of Trucks spawning near it, leads to better rewards since the Repeat Penalty seems to be removed that way. And reloading a save at the Brewery if the Brewery doesn't have a truck seems to work well. Let's say 150 OC every 10 seconds, so that's 15 OC a second, or 54000 an hour. Easy enough to get enough for all the maps.